# How to make facebook apps with .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

Can i create an application that lives inside facebook using .net ? if so what do i need ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try looking [here](http://www.microsoft.com/express/samples/facebook/) - it's a Facebook development kit provided by Microsoft, complete with code samples.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can ,your start will be searching for the facebook api (for .net) then download it and learn how to use it.

thats is.
http://www.codeplex.com/FacebookNET

Answer (score 1):

I've created a VS.NET Starter Kit (C#) for the Facebook Developer Toolkit (see codeplex) [here](http://www.stevetrefethen.com/wiki/Facebook%20application%20development%20in%20ASP.NET.ashx).